# Regex for word exclusion

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will match only the first and third words in the string:

```
term1 and term2
```

My first attempt was `[^(\s|(and))]+`, but it fails because

```
term1 anbd term2
```

gives me these 3 matches: `['term1','b','term2']` whereas I want it to return `['term1','anbd','term2']`

Answer (score 5):

Match only the first and third words: `(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)`

EDIT: If you mean 'match all the words except the word "and"' then: `\b(?!and\b)\S+\b`

Comment: This is the best solution using regular expressions.  Match a word (at least one non-whitespace) then eat up the whitespace, eat up another word, eat up more whitespace, then match another word.  `re.search()` returns a "match group" object, and you can extract the matched strings from that.

Comment: @steveha, I don't think so. Check regex on this sentence `Hello, beautiful world!`. It will match `Hello,` and `world!`, i.e. including punctuation (`,` and `!`).

Comment: @steveha, It is more appropriate use `\b` word boundaries, like in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770681/regex-for-word-exclusion/6771364#6771364

Comment: @polishchuk, it depends on whether he wants punctuation to delimit words, or not.  I agree that it is good to know about the alternatives.  If he is parsing some sort of data file, he might want the above expression rather than the one that knows about punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of regex, consider

```
sentence.split()[:3:2]
```

eg

```
>>> "term1 and term2".split()[:3:2]
['term1', 'term2']
>>> "term1 anbd term2".split()[:3:2]
['term1', 'term2']
>>>
```

Comment: @steveha: it's just "up to the third element, taking every other element". There aren't even any negative numbers involved :)

Comment: Sorry, but my personal definition of "tricky" is: if I look at it and say to myself "What!  What the heck is that doing?!?" then it is "tricky".  Perhaps this means I need to spend more time slicing; maybe it's totally obvious to everyone else. :-)

Comment: By the way, I totally agree with using the `.split()` method function rather than a regex to split the string.  Much as I love regular expressions, the simpler way is best.

Answer (score 1):

You  can use this regex `\b\w+\b` to split your sentence on words, then take 1st and 3rd.

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b')  # pre-compile the pattern
# for this example the pre-compiling doesn't really matter.
temp = re.findall(pat, "Hello, beautiful world!")
lst = [temp[0], temp[2]]  # sets lst to ["Hello", "world"]
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this pattern matches exactly one word.  It is not clear to me how to use this to answer his question.  If you apply this to the string `"Hello, beautiful world!"` this will match `Hello` and I'm not sure how to write a pattern that will discard the comma along with the white space without messing up.  To use this pattern, perhaps it would be better to simply split the string on white space (using the string `.split()` method function) and then use this pattern to strip punctuation off the first and third words found.

Comment: @steveha, I don't know python, but I thought it has similar function to .NET `Regex.Matches` which will return all occurrences of words, i.e.: `Hello`, `beautiful` and `world`.

Comment: I don't usually use it, so I forgot about it, but there is a function `re.findall()` that will find all occurrences of a pattern within a string.  I just tested it and it worked, so I thank you for teaching me something.  Here's the code I tested: `re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', "Hello, beautiful world!")`

Comment: I just edited your answer to include a code sample using `re.findall()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this, it works :)

```
\b([^a].*?\b|a[^n].*?\b|an[^d].*?\b)
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` surround a **character class** - a set of characters to match, or not match. Your regex says "one or more characters, none of which are , `a`, `n` or `d`", which is why you get the result you do.

Getting correct answers to these sorts of things requires correct questions. What's special about the word "and" in your case? Do you want "every word that is not `and`", or do you want "the first and third word of the string, no matter what the words are", or just **what**?

Your description of the desired output in the second case sounds like you want "every word that is not `and`". There are much simpler ways to get this. Regexes are not really as useful as people want them to be.

The `split` method of strings cuts it into words. From there, we can use a list comprehension to filter out any words that are "and". It looks like:

```
[word for word in sentence.split() if word != "and"]
```

See? It's practically plain English.